# Flask with Gevent Blocking Requests on Separate Browser Windows

Tags: python, flask, gevent

In the following snippet, I have a simple web server running that utilizes Flask. It appears as though all requests wait for the previous requests to complete before being processed.

To test, I point two windows in Chrome to localhost:5000. The second waits for the first request to finish completely.

This does not occur when I open one of those windows in 'Incognito' or when running two curl commands simultaneously.

If anyone has an idea why two separate windows get treated as the same connection (and why an incognito one is treated separately), this would be much appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
from gevent import monkey; monkey.patch_all()
monkey.patch_time()

from gevent.pywsgi import WSGIServer


from flask import Flask, Response, jsonify
import json
import time

app = Flask(__name__)

def toJson(obj):
    return json.dumps(obj, indent=None, separators=(',', ':'))

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    print 'Received Request'
    time.sleep(5)
    return Response(toJson({'hello': 'world'}), mimetype='application/json')

print 'Starting Server'
http = WSGIServer(('', 5000), app)
http.serve_forever()
```

Comment: I ran in to the same issue today. Have you found an answer to this question? Related but with no explanation at all: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15000958